# Error in flutter: the default value of an optional parameter must be constant

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen({
    super.key,
    this.location = **const** PlaceLocation( //the default value of  an optional  parameter must be constant.
      latitude: 37.422,
      longitude: -122.084,
      address: '',
    ),
    this.isSelecting = true,
  });

  final PlaceLocation location;
  final bool isSelecting;

  @override
  State<MapScreen> createState() {
    return _MapScreenState();
  }
}
```

I tried to add const and removed, but it doesn't working..
in this code getting error on const..
i need to add default value using my PlaceLocation widget but i cant assign like this.

Comment: If `PlaceLocation` doesn't have a `const` constructor, you can't jut add `const` to its construction sites.